# Weird behavior of CSS (elements are rotated for 180%)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with CSS. I am creating memory game. Problem is that all elements are rotated for 180%. I don't know reason for this...

Here is jsFiddle of game (and problem)

http://jsfiddle.net/uM639/

Here is code that is displaying cards that are rotated:

```
#boxcard {
/*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:1000;
   -moz-perspective:1000;
    -ms-perspective:1000;
     -o-perspective:1000;
        perspective:1000;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard > div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
.flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.front, .back{
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        z-index:2;
  background: #B1B1B1;
   /*   position:absolute;*/

    /*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;

}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
   -moz-transition:0.6s;
     -o-transition:0.6s;
        transition:0.6s;
/*transform-style*/
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
            position:relative;
            float:left;
 /*display: inline-block;
position:relative;*/
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
/* front pane, placed above back */
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back{
/*transform*/

-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Seem to work fine on chrome.

Comment: That's because you've got a style declaring that they must be rotated `180deg`... Check line 83 through 93 for the code block where the style is declared.

Comment: You do not want it to rotate? Btw 180% is 288°

Comment: as you can see cards (images inside of card) is 180% rotated and when you flip card wrong axis is used (X insted of Y)

Comment: Oh, aha! I can see this...in Firefox 20.0. What browser are you using to view this in? (This may just be a CSS3 compatibility issue?)

Comment: I am using Chrome (latest version) @Serlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem (at least why it's happening in Firefox 20.0) is that not all of your CSS3 transforms are the same. If you looks closely at your `.back` and `.flipped` styles, the value for `transform` (not any of the vendor-prefixed versions) is actually wrong. Where is should be `rotateY()`, it is instead solely `rotate()`:

```
.flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg); /* This seems wrong... */
}
```

To fix this, just add in the missing `Y` to that line for both class style definitions:

```
.flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Fixed! */
}

.back{
/*transform*/

-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Fixed! */
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uM639/2/) with the fix. It seems to correct the problem (at least in Firefox 20.0), and still works fine in Google Chrome (so it didn't break anything unexpectedly).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Serlite . Your example of code is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the lines where it says 180deg to 0deg like so:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font: 18px Verdana;
    color: #FFF;
  /*background: #CCC;*/
}
#picbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard {
/*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:1000;
   -moz-perspective:1000;
    -ms-perspective:1000;
     -o-perspective:1000;
        perspective:1000;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard > div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
.flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.front, .back{
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        z-index:2;
  background: #B1B1B1;
   /*   position:absolute;*/

    /*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;

}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
   -moz-transition:0.6s;
     -o-transition:0.6s;
        transition:0.6s;
/*transform-style*/
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
            position:relative;
            float:left;
 /*display: inline-block;
position:relative;*/
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
/* front pane, placed above back */
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back{
/*transform*/

-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(0deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
}
#boxbuttons {
    text-align: center;
/*  margin: 20px;*/
    display: block;
    height: 240px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
        top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
        background-image:url('http://remake.hr/puzzle/images/header6blue.jpg');
}
#boxbuttons .button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EE872A;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#boxbuttons .button:hover {
    background: #999;
}
#info {
    text-align: center;
/*  margin: 20px;*/
    display: block;
    /*height: 500px;*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
        color:black;
}
.botun {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EE872A;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    /*margin: 5px;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
 margin:0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.back{
/*transform*/

-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
}
```

you define here you want the images to be flipped. the class 'back' is added to the divs with the image...